# How to wait for retrofit.getData() complete Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I'm getting data from an API and I need to wait until job is finished. Because of MutableLiveData.
When it's working response.isSusccesful=false then it's changing into true. How do I wait until retrofit.getData() is finished. I tried runblocking but it's not appropriate method. I tried async{} and await() but I didnt make it too.

```
fun loadData():ArrayList<CryptoData> {

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(CryptoAPI::class.java)

    job = viewModelScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            val response = retrofit.getData()

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){

                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    response.body()?.let {
                        cryptoDatas = ArrayList(it)
                        currency.value = cryptoDatas
                        progressBarStatus.value = false
                        println(response.isSuccessful)

                    }
                }
                else{
                    println(response.isSuccessful)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return cryptoDatas
}
```

Comment: You Are already Using `viewModel` Why not use a `LiveData` to Observe the result . Also do not create a `Retrofit` instace for each call create it as Singlton and use it everywhere else

Comment: I'am observing but it's changing after 2 second. I need to set error value if response is not succesful. But it's not succesful  after 2 second it's changing into succesful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should make sure `getData()` is defined as a suspend function so you don't have to fool with those `withContext` wrappers. You don't need them when calling properly written suspend functions, because proper suspend functions don't block, and they delegate to an appropriate dispatcher internally if they need a specific one.

Then you have two choices.

1. Instead of returning something from the function, publish the result to a LiveData (or SharedFlow/StateFlow). The outside class can call this function and observe the LiveData to work with the result.

```
private val _cryptoData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CryptoData>>()
val cryptoData: LiveData<ArrayList<CryptoData>> = _cryptoData

fun loadData() {

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(CryptoAPI::class.java)

    viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = retrofit.getData()
        if (response.isSuccessful){
            response.body()?.let {
                cryptoData.value = ArrayList(it)
                currency.value = it
                progressBarStatus.value = false
                println(response.isSuccessful)
            } 
        else {
            println(response.isSuccessful)
        }
    }
}
```

2. Make `loadData()` a suspend function. Your outside class can use a coroutine to call it and then do something with the result sequentially.

```
suspend fun loadData(): List<CryptoData>? {

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(CryptoAPI::class.java)

    val response = retrofit.getData()
    return if (response.isSuccessful){
        response.body()?.let {
            currency.value = it
            progressBarStatus.value = false
            println(response.isSuccessful)
            ArrayList(it)
        }
    } else {
        println(response.isSuccessful)
        null
    }
}
```

But I'm reading between the lines and guessing this is data you load every time this Fragment or Activity shows. So you should use option 1, except you make this function private and call it from an `init` block. This way, the outside class only needs to observe the LiveData, and if the user rotates the device, it doesn't restart the request each time and delay when the data will finish loading.

Answer (score 0):

If your `getData()` is a `suspend` function you should be all good, because by default code inside coroutines is sequential, meaning nothing below `val response = retrofit.getData()` can run until `getData()` returns.

If it's not just make it a `suspend` function because Retrofit supports it natively.

```
@GET("...")
suspend fun getData(): Response<...>
```

On to the question, you can call `job.join()` to wait for the job's completion, but in your case that won't help you at all. And `join()` is a suspend function, therefore it has to be called either from another `suspend` function or another coroutine.